# WebView возвращение обратно в активити

Tags: java, android

Есть кнопка, с нее запускаю переход по ссылке. Стартует или новый интент или вебвью, адрес открывается без проблем. а Вот когда жму вернуться обратно из браузера в активити появляется пустой экран. Почему так?

```
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("example.com");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
```

или так - результат один пустой стартовый активити:

```
            WebView webview = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
            setContentView(webview);
            webview.loadUrl("http://example.com");
```

onResume присутствует:

```
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.v("MainActivity: ", "onResume" );
}
```

Comment: `setContentView(webview);` заменяет текущий `View` на тот, что передали в параметрах. Нажатие на `Back` само по себе волшебным образом, как ни странно, не вернет предыдущий `View`. Покажите больше кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ты хочешь закрыть `Activity`, а потом вернуться к нему в том же виде, в котором он и закрылся, то, до или после вызова метода `startActivity(new Intent());` не вызывай метод `finish()`. И тогда, при возвращении назад в `Activity`, в твоём случае ты не увидишь пустой экран.

Comment: дело в том, что я так и делаю=) , то есть не закрываю активити при переходе в веб вью. Не могу понять понять почему сбивается отображение в активити

Comment: Напишите полный подробный код. Я так не могу точно дать ответ.

Comment: Хотел только скопировать код, проверил - а он заработал. Пустое окно больше не открывается при обратном переходе. Фантастика.